# pgfplots - |x - 4| + 1 doesn't look correctly

Tags: pgfplots

I want to draw this function: `|x - 4| + 1`, but it looks like this:
[image]

Instead of this:

[image]

Here is part of my `.tex` file

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle, samples=200, xtick={-4,-3,...,10}, ytick={-4,-3,...,10}]
        \addplot[thick, domain=-4:8] {(abs(x - 4)) + 1};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `ymin=0` to your axis spec... (or `ymin=-0.5` perhaps)